# Add some property in the String so response like this

Tags: json

**Hi i want to add some property in the give json string at the time of creating record**
So this is my give Json String

```
{
"id": "123",
"type": "Red",
"bn": "TTY",
"isp": {
    "object": "obj202",
    "time": "19:30",
    "providedBy": {
        "object": "obj201"
    }
},
"seed":35,
"tem": {
    "value": 25,
    "time": "20:20",
    "uc": "CEL"
},  
"loc": {
     "value": {
        "type": "p",
        "coor": [
            2.6,
            9.6
        ]
    }
}
}
```

*IN this string i want to add **type** so response like this*

```
{
"id": "123",
"type": "Red",
"bn": {
    "type": "P",
    "value": "TTY"
},
"isp": {
    "type": "R",
    "providedBy": {
       "type": "R",
        "object": "obj201"
    },
    "object": "obj202"
},
"seed": {
    "type": "P",
    "value": 85
},
"tem": {
    "type": "P",
    "value": 25,
    "time": "20:20",
    "uc": "CEL"
},
"location": {
    "type": "GP",
    "value": {
        "type": "P",
        "coor": [
            2.6,
            9.6
        ]
    }
}}
```

**so please guide me how to do this without using **ObjectMapper** class in the code**

***please provide the code***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39896008/1132056

Comment: thanks , but in my case i don't want to use JSONObject  class object,
i want to do same the in simple string approach